# Get a specific node by its ID?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This sound too dumb to ask but I'm not able to figure out how to get a specific node whose ID is, say, 15

these are what I've tried

```
match (n) where n.id=15 return n

MATCH (n { id:15 }) return n
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [ID](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-id) function, that is to say:

```
WHERE ID(n) = 15
```

Answer (score 2):

use the node function also:

START n=node(12)
RETURN n.name

Lot's of good examples here: http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/

Comment: Start clause is kind of deprecated